# Complex masked text entry storage options

Tags: c#, regex

Odd problem. I have a potential solution, but I'm soliciting improvements. All of this is related to a MS SQL/C# project, so think of things in that context if required.

Making a form for users to enter a bank account number. But different client banks we work with have different (and weird) requirements. This one has numbers that are 13 digits long, but the 2,3 digit are unknown and need to be entered by the user. The trailing 10 digits are zero padded, and 2 or 3 characters on the end should be shown to the user. Basically, nutty. Client specific. A few other clients have various requirements for validation and stuff  I'm trying to knock out with this, so something expandable enough to handle random client requests is what I'm looking for.

So, as an example, somebody might have the partial account number `1__0000123456`. Where they need to enter the missing two digits. But we can show 456. So, want to get that into a masked textbox that displays `1__000???456`, only allowing them to edit the `__s`.

Of course, all this configuration information is stored in a database. Not all people may even be missing numbers digits.

Best solution I've come up with so far is to store the partial number with some magic character to designate missing, probably `_`. Then store a Regex along side of it, which validates and groups regions. But also marks regions with some special crap, like "hidden". Which I figure I can encode in the group name, which is dumb, but the best idea I have.

So, in the database, I might have a record like:

```
Number            Validation
1__0000123456     ^1\d\d0*(?<h:Account Id>123)456$
```

So, we have a number (partial), and a validation expression. But that validation expression has some magic stuff in a named capture group. The ":h" signifies that that range should be hidden. So, I can hide random ranges, or whatever the next crazy client wants.

The above would appear as a masked textbox containing `"1_0000???456"`, where the user was only allowed to enter the second and third digit. Text out to the side could describe what the user was required to enter as "Account Id", the remainder of the named capture group name.

Eh. It's an idea. It feels like an abuse of everything we all hold dear, though.

[EDIT]

So, this doesn't really solve the problem well, as I cannot of course match the value before it's valid: and thus cannot know the ranges to hide or show until after the user enters a valid sequence.  If it was possible to delve into a regex's AST or something... that'd be neato.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, the way you ask for the bank account is specific to a bank. Why not firstly ask for the bank? Then you can load the validation method.

If you cannot ask the user to choose the bank (maybe requirements don't allow you), I think your only option is to check for the right validator on the fly while the user enters the bank account.